# Hi I'm following this tutorial and I can't see the "modified cube" in the final render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, units

Hi I'm following this **tutorial** and I can't see the *"modified cube"*  in the final render.

Here's a link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icMn25j2yy0&t=823s

attached is how it looks on my render[image: the modified cube is missing]

link to my blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFbg0M_jkSuX3042OoEth_sOYUIG3Nvx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. And what's the problem and question you are facing...

Comment: @Y-King The cube that was turned into a ring can't be seen in the final render. It's where those spikey things should be attached at. Pls check the blend file and the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set the cube of for rendering. Go to the outliner, press on the filter icon in the top right, and select the camera under `Restriction Toggles`. Then you can see if that symbol is selected or not for your cube, if it isn't, turn it on, if it is, sorry, but I can't help you then.

Comment: it did'nt work, when  I checked it. It's turned on, thanks anyway